# Aplicación Android - Almacenar datos de encuesta en una base de datos

Tags: java, android, android-studio

estoy haciendo una encuesta, y quisiera saber que puedo hacer para que las respuestas queden registradas en una base de datos del celular, al hacer click en el botón "Resultados".

Acá esta mi código Java:

```
Button sig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.env); // cargo el boton

sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText preg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText preg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        RadioButton botonun = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        RadioButton botondo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        RadioButton botontr = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        RadioButton botoncu = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        RadioButton botonci = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        RadioButton botonse = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
        RadioButton botonsi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
        RadioButton botonoc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
        RadioButton botonnu = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
        RadioButton botondi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
        RadioButton botonon = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
        RadioButton botondc = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
        String strNombre = nom.getText().toString();
        String strPregCinco = preg5.getText().toString();
        String strPregCuatro = preg4.getText().toString();

        if(strNombre.matches("") || strPregCinco.matches("") ||
            strPregCuatro.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡Dejaste campos vacíos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if(botonun.isChecked() == false && botondo.isChecked() == false && 
            botontr.isChecked() == false && botoncu.isChecked() == false &&
            botonci.isChecked() == false && botonse.isChecked() == false &&
            botonsi.isChecked() == false && botonoc.isChecked() == false &&
            botonnu.isChecked() == false && botondi.isChecked() == false &&
            botonon.isChecked() == false && botondc.isChecked() == false) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"¡No marcaste algunas respuestas!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
            Toast.makeText(context, "¡Encuesta enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(pas);
        }
    }
});
```

Y mi código XML de los botones de resultados:

```
<Button
    android:text="Resultados profesores"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/encuesta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:elevation="0dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Resultados 11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button0"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Resultados 9"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Resultados 8"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que crear una base de datos y almacenar los datos en ella. En Android se usa SQLite como motor de base de datos.

Aquí tienes un tutorial sobre [base de datos en Android en español](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/bases-de-datos-en-android-i-primeros-pasos/) (enlace al [contenido completo](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/curso-de-programacion-android/indice-de-contenidos/)) y también puedes echar un vistazo a la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html?hl=es) de Android sobre base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

hola lo mejor es que implementes las bases de datos SQLite,te dejo el diseño base para la creacion de una tabal junto con la referencia de la busqueda de informacion y desde donde te sera util la informacion

referencia:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage?hl=es-419#db

Cómo utilizar las bases de datos
Android ofrece compatibilidad total con las bases de datos SQLite. Cualquier clase dentro de la aplicación, no fuera de ella, será posible acceder por nombre a cualquier base de datos que crees.

El método recomendado para crear una nueva base de datos SQLite consiste en crear una subclase de SQLiteOpenHelper y anular el método de onCreate(), en el cual puedes ejecutar un comando de SQLite a fin de crear tablas en la base de datos. Por ejemplo:

public class DictionaryOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME = "dictionary";
private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DICTIONARY_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            KEY_WORD + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_DEFINITION + " TEXT);";

DictionaryOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

}

Puedes obtener una instancia de tu implementación de SQLiteOpenHelper mediante el constructor definido. Para realizar operaciones de lectura y escritura en la base de datos, llama a getWritableDatabase() y getReadableDatabase(), respectivamente. Estas dos opciones muestran un objeto SQLiteDatabase que representa la base de datos y proporciona métodos para las operaciones de SQLite.

Android no impone ninguna limitación más allá de los conceptos de SQLite estándares. No recomendamos incluir un campo clave-valor de aumento automático que pueda usarse como ID único para buscar un registro rápidamente. Esto no se requiere en el caso de los datos privados, pero si implementas un proveedor de contenido, debes incluir un ID único mediante la constante BaseColumns._ID.

Puedes ejecutar consultas de SQLite a través de los métodos de SQLiteDatabase query(), los cuales aceptan varios parámetros de consulta, como la tabla para consulta, la proyección, la selección, las columnas y el agrupamiento, entre otros. En el caso de consultas complejas, como aquellas que requieren alias de columna, debes usar SQLiteQueryBuilder, el cual ofrece diferentes métodos convenientes para crear consultas.

Cada consulta de SQLite mostrará un Cursor que señale todas las filas que encontró la consulta. El Cursor siempre es el mecanismo con el cual puedes navegar por los resultados de una consulta de la base de datos, y leer filas y columnas.

Para hallar ejemplos de apps que demuestren la forma de usar las bases de datos SQLite en Android, consulta las aplicaciones del bloc de notas y el diccionario de búsquedas.

Comment: Hola!!! gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder. sin embargo, esta es una pregunta de hace mas de dos años, y puede que no recibas ninguna respuesta de quien pregunto.