# ¿Cómo cierro un fragment?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Se que puede ser algun método o algo simple pero no encuentro como hacerlo.

Método para cerrar fragment:

[image]

No he llegado a trabajar con fragments, estoy aprendiendo a utilizarlos.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812922/how-to-close-the-current-fragment-by-using-button-like-the-back-button
A lo mejor esto pueda ayudarte

Comment: @L.Ronquillo Gracias, era lo que buscaba...

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado creo que lo mismo que esta [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/53293/aplicaci%C3%B3n-android-almacenar-datos-de-encuesta-en-una-base-de-datos/53330#53330] ... buscando perfiles para simplemente hacer comentarios negativos o sin sentido ?

Comment: @LeonardoHenao Sólo busco un uso correcto de las etiquetas. Que estés usando "android-studio" no significa que el problema sea de "android-studio", este problema es de "android" independientemente de la plataforma de desarrollo usada. Otro tema sería si tienes problemas con configuraciones, módulos, etc. de "android-studio" o puedes creer que el problema puede deberse a ello, cosa que no veo mencionada por ningún lado.

Comment: @JoseD.Jurado y en tus publicaciones hablas de android studio ? no veo ninguna de android studio con etiquetas de android studio.

Comment: @LeonardoHenao No, no he tenido ningún problema con android studio por tanto ni tengo publicaciones ni etiquetas de android studio. No veo la relevancia de lo que has puesto con respecto al correcto uso de la etiqueta, si acaso darme la razón.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Los `Fragments` a diferencia de las `Activity`, no pueden ser "cerrados", en su caso pueden ser **removidos** del Activity que los contiene.

Si usas la librería de soporte, usa `getSupportFragmentManager()`, definiendo el id del frame que contiene el `Fragment`:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame)).commit();
```

Si no estas usando la library de soporte:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame)).commit();
```

---

Si te encuentras en el mismo Fragment y usas la library de support:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```

Si no usas la library de soporte:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
```